# Multiple hostPath volumeMounts with Kubernetes: only one works

Tags: kubernetes

My pod specification file

```
  - name: temp1-cont
    image: temp1-img:v2
    env:
      - name: CONFIG_MODE
        value: "manager"
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /bin/tipc-config
        name: tipc-vol
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /etc/
        name: config-vol
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: "100Mi"
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: "100Mi"
    command: ["/etc/init.d/docker-init"]
  volumes:
    - name: tipc-vol
      hostPath:
        path: /opt/tipc-config
        type: FileOrCreate
    - name: config-vol
      hostPath:
        path: /opt/config/
        type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

I am using two hostPath volumes namely tipc-vol and config-vol
But when i create the pod only one volume is mounted which is incidentally the last volume mounted on the container

```
  temp1-cont:
    Container ID:
    Image:         temp1-img:v2
    Image ID:
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /etc/init.d/docker-init
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 09 Jun 2020 09:36:57 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  100Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  100Mi
    Environment:
      CONFIG_MODE:  manager
    Mounts:
      /etc/ from config-vol (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-g2ltz (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  tipc-vol:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /opt/tipc-config
    HostPathType:  FileOrCreate
  config-vol:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /opt/config/
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
  default-token-g2ltz:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-g2ltz
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Guaranteed
```

In the k8s doc, nothing like this is mentioned.
I am trying to test my application so I am using hostVolume and not persistent volume.
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have two separate `volumeMounts:` blocks, and their lists don't get merged.  Delete the second `volumeMounts:` line.

Comment: Yes its working, i don't know how I missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Update pod volume mounts like following

```
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /bin/tipc-config
        name: tipc-vol
      - mountPath: /etc/
        name: config-vol
```

So, your pod yaml will be

```
 - name: temp1-cont
    image: temp1-img:v2
    env:
      - name: CONFIG_MODE
        value: "manager"
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /bin/tipc-config
        name: tipc-vol
      - mountPath: /etc/
        name: config-vol
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: "100Mi"
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: "100Mi"
    command: ["/etc/init.d/docker-init"]
  volumes:
    - name: tipc-vol
      hostPath:
        path: /opt/tipc-config
        type: FileOrCreate
    - name: config-vol
      hostPath:
        path: /opt/config/
        type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the second `volumeMounts:`. So below should work

```
volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /bin/tipc-config
    name: tipc-vol
  - mountPath: /etc/
    name: config-vol
```